# How can I find element by non-unique resousre-id?

Tags: selenium, appium, selenide

I test an application which use non-unique `resourse-id` for elements.

Is there any way to find such elements by xpath like

```
//*[@resourse-id='non-unique-id'][2]
```

I mean the second element with same `resourse-id`.

Comment: Update the question with text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend avoiding xpath in mobile automation since this is the most time-consuming strategy to find elements. 
If you don't have any other anchors for your elements but you confident in its order, you can stick to the following approach: Appium driver can return a list of elements with the same locator, in case of Page Object model you can either do this way:

```java
@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "resourceIdMatches(\".*whatever\")")
private List<MobileElement> elements;
```

so, once your page is initialized, you can access an element by index:

```java
elements.get(1).click();
```

or, in case of manual managenemt, you can do this way:

```java
List<MobileElement> elements = driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("resoureceIdMatches(\".*whatever\")"));
elements.get(3).click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need to generate getter for every private field to get access to fields in case of Page Object model or there is any easier ways?

Comment: Actually it depends on your test framework architecture, but if we are talking about the multi-layer model, your Page Objects should only expose the accessors with the friendly names, e.g.: `void clickCancelButton()` or `List<String> getListedItemsNames()`. In this case your steps (or actions) layer does not depend on PO implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, you need to select the second element with the path as mentioned: `//*[@resourse-id='non-unique-id']`

To do that, you need to first grab all the elements with the same non-unique resource ID and then `get()` them. So, your code should be:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@resourse-id='non-unique-id']")).get(1).click();
```

The index for any list starts at 0. So, the second element can be accessed through the value of 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try following approach:

```
(//*[@resourse-id='non-unique-id'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML with non-unique ids is not a valid HTML document.

So, for the sake of future testability, ask the developers to fix the ids.